# Eclipse adapter factory implementation

Tags: design-patterns, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, adapter

I am new to Eclipse Adapter concept. However I do have some experience in Eclipse RCP.

I searched in internet to get the idea about Eclipse Adapter pattern. 
I got the idea that it transforms one object to another object. Especially what I understood is,
if we check both the object reference(Adapter and Adaptable) it will be same(My understanding, Please correct me If I am wrong.).
I saw one article in internet  that converting of Apple to Orange.

https://dzone.com/articles/eclipse-adapters-hand-hand-hol

It does not contain full source code. So I started implemented in my own way.
And I got stuck in `getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class<T>  adapterType)` method of  AdaptorFactory class. 
I am confused to implement the getAdapter(adaptable,adapter)method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAdapter` is not normally used to create a new object. Instead it is used to access some existing object that the source object contains.

Often the source object is a user interface object - perhaps a node of a tree structure, and the type being request is something like the file that the node represents.

```java
public class TreeNodeFactory implements IAdapterFactory {

    private static final Class<?>[] adapterList = { IFile.class };

    @Override
    public <T> T getAdapter(Object sourceObject, Class<T> adapterType) {
        if (adapterType == IFile.class) {
            if (sourceObject instanceof TreeNode) {
                return (T) ((TreeNode)sourceObject).getFile();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?>[] getAdapterList() {
        return adapterList;
    }
}
```

Note that here I am calling a `TreeNode.getFile` method which will return the `IFile` that the node represents.

Using `getAdapter` means that the calling code does not need to know anything about `TreeNode`, it can just ask for an `IFile`.

Comment: Hi Many thanks for the information, Still I am not very clear, in the, getAdapter(adaptable,adapter)method of  AdaptorFactory class
if I wanted get an existing(Orange) object,  in which way I have to write? Could you please give me
the hint? In the following way I expect. 
Apple apple = new Apple();
Orange orange = (Orange) apple.getAdapter(Orange.class);

Comment: Is the current implementation  getAdapter(adaptable,adapter)method of AdaptorFactory class right? becuase it always creates new object. How to rewrite the code which can reuse for taking the orange object? it would be very helpful if you could tell that as well.

Comment: You have to do what I did in my example, for you something like `((Apple) sourceObject).getOrange()` and you have to write a `getOrange` method in `Apple`